# Random 2D slice from 3D volume

Tags: math

I want to get a random 2D slice from a 3D volume in a computer program for generating noise. I decided to use a rotation matrix, which I understand has to be a member of the rotation group SO(3). How can I create a uniformly random member of this group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose three random values u<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>, and u<sub>3</sub> between 0 and 1.

A uniform random quaternion [is given by](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node198.html):

- w = sqrt(1 - u<sub>1</sub>)sin(2pi*u<sub>2</sub>)
- x = sqrt(1 - u<sub>1</sub>)cos(2pi*u<sub>2</sub>)
- y = sqrt(u<sub>1</sub>)sin(2pi*u<sub>3</sub>)
- z = sqrt(u<sub>1</sub>)cos(2pi*u<sub>3</sub>)

You can then generate the appropriate rotation matrix using [this formula](http://www.flipcode.com/documents/matrfaq.html#Q54):

```
    |       2     2                                |
    | 1 - 2y  - 2z    2xy - 2zw      2xz + 2yw     |
    |                                              |
    |                       2     2                |
M = | 2xy + 2zw       1 - 2x  - 2z   2yz - 2xw     |
    |                                              |
    |                                      2     2 |
    | 2xz - 2yw       2yz + 2xw      1 - 2x  - 2y  |
    |                                              |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a random 3D vector, formed by the composition of three independent random variables as each axis. You can then define this vector to be the normal vector of your random 2D slice as well as the distance of that 2D slice from the origin. I'm pretty sure (although without a formal proof) that this approach should give a uniform distribution over possible 2D slices (That previous statement is fundamentally informal).

Edit: On second thought, you should probably draw an independent variable to represent the distance of the 2D slice from the origin. Otherwise, you'll have a distribution of 2D slices that are more likely to be around a certain distance away from the origin.

Comment: In order to get a uniform direction from 3 random numbers chosen from `[-1..1]`, you will need to reject vectors whose length is greater than `1`.  To avoid instability, you may also wish to reject vectors whose length is less then a fairly small value (say `0.1`).  Note that "reject" means to generate 3 fresh random numbers, and repeat the above until you generate a vector that isn't rejected (which should happen quickly, on average).